# ??? Question Marks?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

**Challenge**

Create a function that takes an string as a parameter. (Easy as far)

This string will contain

- Single digit numbers
- Letters from the alphabet
- Question marks (Of course)

Your function will check if there are exactly `3 question marks` between every pair of two numbers that add up to 10 or more. If so, then your function should return `truthy`, otherwise it should return  `falsey`.

If there are not any two numbers that add up to 10 or more in the string, your function should return false.

**Rules**

- Input must be a string
- Output must be `truthy` or `falsey` value
- If string contains only one number or none return `falsey`
- If string contains odd amount of single digits, ignore the last one (left to right)

**Example**

Given: `"arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5"`

Your function must output `true` because 
there are exactly `3 question marks` between `6` and `4`, and `3 question marks` between `5` and `5` at the end of the string

---

Given: `"a4sd???9dst8?3r"`

Your function must output `false` because there is just a `single question mark` between `8` and `3`

**Test Cases**

**Input:** `"aa6?9"`

**Output:** `false`

---

**Input:** `"acc?7??sss?3rr1??????5"`

**Output:** `true`

---

**Input:** `"sdty5???xcd8s3"`

**Output:** `true`

---

**Input:** `"sthfer5dfs"`

**Output:** `false`

---

### Update (Some clarification points)

- Once you use a number to pair with other, you can not use it again.
- You only can pair consecutive numbers (left to right). Example `"as4f???6sda3?3d"` the pairs are `4-6` and `3-3`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes win.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76615/discussion-on-question-by-luis-felipe-de-jesus-munoz-question-marks).

Comment: The "Once you use a number to pair with other, you can not use it again." part is still not very clear. Perhaps you meant "only consider gaps at even indices", something like that.

Comment: Any reason why you special-cased the "1 number or none" case?

Comment: This question appears to be taken from [here](https://coderbyte.com/editor/guest:Questions%20Marks:JavaScript).

Comment: Yes it is @Laikoni

Comment: In that case, you should give attribution and make sure that you are not violating any copyright by posting the challenge here.

Comment: Under [https://coderbyte.com/Terms/](https://coderbyte.com/Terms/) you find "Don't Copy From Us. You agree not to copy, imitate, mirror, reproduce, distribute, publish, download, display, perform, post, store, or transmit any of Coderbyte's content, including without limitation any marks, in any form or by any means, including but not limited to electronic, mechanical, photocopying, recording, or otherwise. "

Comment: @Laikoni that doesn't apply for public challenges. I did not sigh any term and conditions

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 148 bytes

```python
def f(a):q=[a.group(1).count("?")==3for a in re.finditer("(?=((\d+)\D+(\d+)))",a)if 10==sum(map(int,a.groups()[1:]))];return any(q)*all(q)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xDoIwFEV3v6Jhek8JkSAOmKaLfwEMRVptAm15tAl8PTbG6dzlnOv38HG2Oo5RaaZBYrPwVhZvctFDicXLRRsgExlyXmlHTDJjGalCGzuaoAgyEBygGy/YPS8/Ima5RKNZeeV8jTPM0oOxIf93V8C2bHrE/kEqRLJM2h0WPMtpSjiZ2TsK6eTwlDTQSfYxQAofkmi4CyFu2zZMdRpKqfoL)

Comment: Doesnt work with complex strings like `arrb6???4xxbl5???eee5`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz sorry, had my condition backwards.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 126 bytes

`all*any` idea is by @HyperNeutrino, checkout [his answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163449/66855)

```python
def f(n):r=[sum(map(int,g[0::2]))>9for g in re.findall('(\d)(.*?)(\d)',n)if 3==g[1].count('?')];return all(r)*any(r)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LVDBboMwDD3DV0RcklQZWkvpVibqD2EcKEloJAjICRJ8PQsdvvjZz@9Z9rT612gv2yaVJppZXmBZuXlgQzMxY73oqs@iuNScP@56RNIRYwmqVBsrm75nlP1KztIT8B1QYbnRJCvLrjrXaTvO1jMKlNc/qPyMluwa5KfGriHFZphG9MFv272NnWa/@1eJ8y@tMJfaJSKOoqRpbnA/IOLzBgDXZXn2eQBKqfyg2ha@AJxzkCGe4R0H56Rf9@mlld8uS0KrLuJownDj/2JB6MeDivCEd8m3Pw)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 125 bytes

Ouputs `[]` for false and `[True]` for true

```python
def f(n):r=[sum(map(int,g[0::2]))>9for g in re.findall('(\d)(.*?)(\d)',n)if 3==g[1].count('?')];return r[:1]*all(r)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBBboMwEDzDKywutiMHFQhpQ0T8EMqBYJtYAoPWRiKvp3ZL9zSzszPa3eXtXrPJ911IhRQxtIK6setEpm4h2jg2NB9VlbeUPm5qBjQgbRDIVGkjunEkmHwLStITpwFgZqhWqKjrocnatJ9X4wjmmLZ3kG4Fb22qrD0FJ9BYT8sMzsftIVqbZXUhvkmseykJpVA2YXEUJV135bd/mHHO84MAPK@eXrbtOZYeSCnLQ@p7/sm5tZYXAMHj69CscO8wvfXiyxaJb7VVHC3g7/3bgiF8fmDmH/JL6f4D)