# Equal Pair sum of 10?

Tags: code-golf, string, number

## Challenge :

Check :

- if there are exactly `n` exclamation marks `!` between every `pair`
- and whether the sum of **each** pair equals to 10.

---

## Input :

- A string of arbitary length.
- The number of exclamation marks to check for

---

## Output :

if there are exactly `n` exclamation marks between each pair, return truthy value, otherwise falsy value.

---

## Pair :

**Pair** is defined as two digits with **at least** one exclamation mark between them

---

## Note :

- The string may contain

  - lowercase letters
  - digits (1-9)
  - space
  - and obviously exclamation marks (`!`)
- In case no digit pair is found, return a falsy value.
- The exclamation will not appear at start or end of the string

---

## Examples :

```
asas6!!4somevbss5!!asa5 , 2                ---> true
sasdasd3!2ssjdn3! sdf!3 , 1                ---> false
asjsj8sj!!!! 2 sjsadasd9!!!!1 , 4          ---> true
sal7!!3 , 2                                ---> true
nodtejsanhf , 2                            ---> true
2is digit no excla 5 , 8                   ---> true
a!1!9!8!2!a  , 1                           ---> true (thanks @ngn)
```

The last two cases were `false` imo but as suggested by Adam (who has more experience than me and probably knows better :) ), they were made true

---

## Winning criteria :

this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each language wins.

---

## Don't forget :

You must check whether the sum of the two numbers equals 10 or not too, along with whether each pair is separated via `n` exclamation marks

---

## Credit ? :

@Laikoni found a challenge on coderbyte similar to this : [Here](https://coderbyte.com/editor/guest:Questions%20Marks:JavaScript). O_o ? I didn't know that

---

## Some explanation :

@ngn suggested this case `a!!1!2!3a45!6!!a , 1` (return false)

```
a!!      --> ignore this 
1        --> here we go start 
!        --> sum so far = 1
2        --> sum = 3, and stop
```

Yep the sum of each pair must be 10 and since the sum of the first pair wasn't 10, no need to go on. :)

Comment: [*Very* closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/163445/42963).

Comment: I recommend [the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#show-editor-button) to iron out issues such as these before posting to Main.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, if that challenge wasn't (currently) closed, I'd dupehammer this.

Comment: @Shaggy : We can always reopen that and close this

Comment: This has 4 down-votes ? O_o ? why

Comment: @MuhammadSalman I think the downvotes are due to lack of specification clarity at posting time. The Sandbox would have helped.

Comment: `a!1!9!8!2!a` - isn't `9!8` a "pair"?

Comment: @ngn : It would be __if__ `1!9` weren't a pair

Comment: By the definition currently given ("Pair is defined as two digits with at least one exclamation mark between them") `9!8` is a pair. (Furthermore `1!9!8` is too, somewhat more debatable though).

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>62</s> 48 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts stdin for string and then for `n`. Now handles cases like `a!1!9!!8!2!a`. Thanks to ngn for saving a bunch of bytes while pointing out failure of some unlisted test cases. Assumes `⎕IO` (**I**ndex **O**rigin) to be `0`, which is default on many systems.

```apl
∧/(⎕=¯2+≢¨m),0=10|+/⎕D⍳↑m←'\d!+\d'⎕S'&'⊢⍞∩⎕D,'!'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY49TsNAEIX7PcVOw4IcFHsdJ06RLg0VBW2ahXUSW/6TJkJEok4MUhAUtBRpgIqCG@QocxFnHCmyn6aZT@@9GVOm13Zt0mJR09vnzS1t3l1B1basqfruXzKbHP60Qy/7w0921XMnnvvs9BlPafdPm4@MA2pmwZlZxfROXSh63dPui6rfxtVToLhqW8uTSmHQ4BBggEUWPd4jBgCMAqHF2cEGy@ODRkxs7oNEOwdfeKLtSDAJMQGW1JI30yTGze6JQacpHQEn2@68sKuI7fly3qE6RmnjRbySeSGjp4fUyECE7TnwYAwhaDDdJ070jI8)

`⎕D,'!'` concatenate the **D**igits and an exclamation point.

`⍞∩` prompt for string and find the intersection with the above (removes all irrelevant chars)

`⊢i←` store in `i` (for **i**nput) and yield that

`'\d!+\d'⎕S'&'` PCRE **S**earch for a digit, a "!" run, a digit

`m←` store in `m` (for **m**atches)

`↑` mix the list of strings into a character matrix, padding with spaces

`⎕D⍳` find the **ɩ**ndex of each character in the **D**igits (i.e. "0" → 0, "1" → 1,… "!" and " " → 10)

`+/` sum each row (i.e. each pair)

`10|` division remainder when divided by 10 (non-digits do not affect this result)

`0=` is it 0? (i.e. divisible by ten; max is 18 and min is 2, so no false positives)

`(`…`),` prepend the following:

`≢¨m` tally (count the length of) each **m**atch

`¯2+` less 2 (for the two digits, i.e. length of the "!" run)

`⎕=` prompt for `n`; is it equal to the lengths?

`∧/` are they all true? (AND reduction)

Comment: @MuhammadSalman Now it has an explanation. APL is really not very hard to understand. I'll be happy to teach you in [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard).

Comment: And I would love to learn. Will check that out

Comment: `'(\d)!+(\d)'⎕S'\1\2'` -> `'!'~⍨¨'\d!+\d'⎕S'&'`

Comment: `+/¨⍎¨¨(⊂'55'),` -> `+/⎕d⍳↑` (⎕io←0)

Comment: `⍵='!+'⎕S 1⊢i` - this condition is wrong, there may be extra `'!'`s that are not part of pairs

Comment: `10=+/⎕D⍳↑∩∘⎕D¨` -> `0=10|+/↑⎕D⍳⍪↑` this is tricky, note that there are no `'0'`s in the input and that the sum of two digits can't be >18 (so, if the sum is a multiple of 10, it must be 10)

Comment: reuse the matches instead of the regex: [`∧/(⎕=¯2+≢¨r),0=10|+/↑⎕D⍳⍪↑r←'\d!+\d'⎕S'&'⊢⍞∩⎕D,'!'`](https://tio.run/##TY49TsNAEIX7PcVOw4IcFHsdg1OkS0NFQZtmYZ1gy9hWJkJBok4MkhEUtBRp@GlS5AY5ylzEjCNF9mib9817b9YU6bl9Mmk@q@nt8@qaVu@uoHJd1FR@90@ZjfZb7dDLZv8zP@u5I899dvq0@uDNmKodVX8s5hxTEwvOxCpe3KgTRa8bqr6o/G2MPQWKC9e1PEwhDBq8ABhg/hA93iIGAIwCocXRwQbLzweNmNjMB4l2Cr7wRNuRYBJiAjxSS1amSQwb7YlBpym9BE623VluFxHbs/tph@oYpY1n8UJmuYyWd6mRgQjbc@DBEELQYLqfONAj/gc)

Comment: @ngn Thank you. I removed the two no-ops from your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 94 bytes

```python
lambda s,c:all(sum(map(int,r))==10for r in re.findall('(\d).*?%s.*?(\d)'%('!'*c),s))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7vasMgFMW/9ynuDZRoCWUx7ZYOwl6kX2xMWoN/gteN7ekz7cbIKiJez@8cz/wVb96JxXTnxUh7URKo6l@lMYzeLbNyZtrFKnDedfXT6AME0A7CsB@1Uxkr2Vnx/e5tS@nI93LLSix3Pa@I8422sw8xGZY5pCQwrJAk6RnxQN4OHxeiI2J6OhZQgeCbPyxRKu0GBdGkXINAasQmY/UKkzTR1NKEaYGANMlsO@W5zvDhX6Z5wZ@M9VfOqzgko7uNj5LQBEpfdQTnYfjsjYR703ZdAWs8YYsCZQGP9e7ar5il5Rs)